# How to open a new board with Trello's API

Tags: javascript, api, trello

From [API](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/board):
[image: Trello API]

Yet this fails:

```
  Trello.rest('GET', `/members/me/boards/${id}`, {actions:['createBoard']})
```

with this error:

```
  responseText:"Cannot GET /1/members/me/boards/fkdsjg412?key=14aeebb47bb7ce6b306894ccf6c5c4cf&token=618302133a76be5f3f631466f1989edcaca4156a92ae2175d0d25aee1065d4c3&actions%5B%5D=createBoard"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved it:

```
 Trello.rest('POST', `boards`, {name: boardName});
```

Still have not idea what the *actions* parameter I mentioned in the original question does.

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem with my Python project. Trello seriously needs to clean up their documentation. Total cluster **** on their part.